# Hance/Hence connection?

Tags: etymology, orthography, history, historical-change

In researching the verb 'hence' I noted the several forms listed in the OED, two of which were: "hennes or henes" from Middle English usage. Similarly with the verb 'hance' I noted that scholars have declared this words origin having come through French and Latin as "haunce or haunse" etc. Since both words first appeared in English, circa 1290-1303 respectively, I am curious to know if 'hance' was ever used as 'hannes or hanes' in English literature. If so, where can this source be found?

Comment: If the OED doesn’t have any by-forms _hannes_ or _hanes_ (and it doesn’t), then it’s highly unlikely that such forms are attested. The OED is usually very diligent in noting alternative spellings, and for _hance_, it only has _hawnce_, _hawnse_, _haunse_, _haanse_, _hanse_, _haunce_. The reason _hence_ has those variant earlier spellings is etymological: the origin of the word is the adverb _henne_ + the genitive suffix _-s_. The spelling _hence_ is secondary, to avoid it being pronounced [hεnz], like _hens_.

Comment: "Similarly" how? Also, "the verb *hence*" derived from the adjective, or the adjective? What makes you think *hannes* is plausible?

Comment: I don't understand the question. OED tells me the verb ***to hence** = to drive away* derives (figuratively) through *hence = the other world = elsewhere (than in this world); in the next world. **Obs.*** Completely unrelated to (also obsolete) ***to hance** = to raise, lift, elevate, exalt*, which has a tortuous and uncertain etymology, and is apparently related to ***to enhance** = to raise (the height of)*. Why are *both* these words being asked about? And can we reinstate closevote reason "Too Localised", please?

Comment: @FumbleFingers- Its a small research objective I am working on. I have learned in the past that some words have uncertain etymologies as you stated. Even as good as the OED is there may be a few mistakes or lingering uncertainties. I surmised that 'hence' with the two forms I included with it, might be applicable to 'hance' as well being that there is only one letter difference between the two words. I am well aware of the difference in their meanings, it is their Middle to Old English origins I am interested in exploring. Whatever I find will bring closure to my research.

Comment: @JonHanna- Refer to my comment to FumbleFingers.

Answer (score 1):

> I am curious to know if 'hance' was ever used as 'hannes or hanes' in
>   English literature. If so, where can this source be found?

[c1400(1375) Canticum Creat.(Trin-O 57)](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=75549086&egdisplay=compact&egs=75564225)

It's not a verb there, but I understand you to be looking merely for a possible relationship?